# Return multiline string as part of REST api

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, rest, multilinestring

I'm looking to return a multi-line string as part of a REST Get request.

I have the following list:

```
items = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to convert it into a string with the line breaks in between. So i did this:

```
items = "\n".join(items)
```

Here is the code block I have:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
   items = [1,2,3,4,5]
   items = "\n".join(items)
   return items
```

The response that I get is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

However, I'm expecting:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using this

```
items = "<br/>".join(map(str, items))
```

should work. Basically html will ignore new lines as such.That's what `<br/>` is for

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Inserting a "br" tag will only display results as new lines while parsing in flask

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
   items = [1,2,3,4,5]
   items2 = '<br>'.join(str(e) for e in items)
   return items2
```

### Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the code it works

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def test():
    items = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
    items = "<br />".join(items)
    return items

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run()
```